# Esconder a ActionBar em um fragment mas mostrar em outro

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que está sendo feito praticamente todo com base em `fragments`. Até agora, eu tenho apenas uma `activity` e 4 `fragments`, dentro dos quais preciso que somente um deles não tenha a `ActionBar`. Os métodos comuns de se esconder a ActionBar não funcionaram (`getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();`). De qual maneira posso fazer isso?

Este é o fragment que não desejo ter a ActionBar:

```
package com.renanlazarotto.fserv.fragments;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.Button;

        import com.renanlazarotto.fserv.activities.FservActivity;
        import com.renanlazarotto.fserv.R;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((FservActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.titulo_login);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

        Button logar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button_entrar);

        logar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ChamadosFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de um pouco de pesquisa, percebi que aparentemente não é possível esconder a `ActionBar` em apenas um `Fragment` sem afetar os outros. Dessa forma, resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira:

```
public static void mostrarActionBar(Activity parent) {
    ActionBarActivity abc = (ActionBarActivity) parent;
    abc.getSupportActionBar().show();
}
public static void esconderActionBar(Activity parent) {
    ActionBarActivity abc = (ActionBarActivity) parent;
    abc.getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Onde o parâmetro parent é passado como referência da qual `Activity` o `Fragment` pertence (usando o método `getActivity()`):

```
esconderActionBar(getActivity());
```